# How to install drivers for ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, catalyst

I followed a [guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Lucid_Installation_Guide) to install drivers for my graphic card, However when I restart, Ubuntu merely shows a blank screen. I can get a terminal through <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but that's about it. Where exactly am I going wrong, and what exactly can I do to fix my current situation?

I use a laptop with an external monitor and a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Comment: Firstly, the guide you followed is not for 12.04. What you should have done is go the "System Settings"  >> "Additional Drivers" and select the Ubuntu Proprietary Driver.  It was yesterday when you asked the question, have you made any progress.

Comment: have you try this http://askubuntu.com/a/131027/32413 ?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the terminal with Ctrl Alt F1 like you said.

The command `dpkg -l '*nv*`' wil list all the the installed packages containing "nv".
With me the offending package was "nvidia-current".

Type `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current`. Type your password if asked for.

Reboot your machine and viola. Well it worked for me. Hopefully you will be successful too.